# moq verify method was called with stream of data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, memorystream

I have a method that calls another method with a stream. I would like to test that the data inserted in the first method is what is sent in the second.

```
public MyMessage Parse(byte[] data)
{
    return myDependency.Read(new MemoryStream(data))
}
```

In my test, I have something like the following

```
byte [] mockData = { 116, 101, 115, 116};

sut.Parse(mockData);

mockDependency.Verify(x=>x.Read(...));
```

Now my question is, what is the correct thing I should have in place of `...`?

I can do something like `(It.IsAny<MemoryStream>())`, but that does not actually verify that it was called with the given data.

I tried something like `It.Is<MemoryStream>(s=>s.Equals(new MemoryStream(data)))` but that failed.

Is there a way for me to test that the data sent to `Parse` is the same data send in the memory stream to `Read`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried something like `It.Is<MemoryStream>(s=>s.Equals(new MemoryStream(data)))` but that failed.

In this case it could have been done like

```
mockDependency.Verify(_ => _.Read(It.Is<MemoryStream>( s => 
    Enumerable.SequenceEqual(s.ToArray(), data))));
```

by comparing the byte arrays

You can also try capturing the passed argument so that is can be better inspected during assertion

For example

```
// Arrange
byte [] expectedData = { 116, 101, 115, 116 };
byte [] actualData = null;

//...

mockDependency
    .Setup(_ => _.Read(It.IsAny<MemoryStream>()))
    .Callback((MemoryStream ms) => actualData = ms.ToArray())
    .Returns(/* MyMessage here*/)
    .Verifiable();

// Act
sut.Parse(expectedData);

//Assert
mockDependency.Verify(); //verify that setup was invoked as expected
//using FluentAssertions to check data
actualData.Should().NotBeNull()
.And.BeEquivalentTo(expectedData);
```

Note that [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) was used to simplify the assertion of the collection.